# Infinitesimal in Real Number?

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

Although not have anything about hyperreal, My real calculus book says that infinitesimal means situation that  something smaller than any positive number, but larger than zero, similar as that infinity means situtation that something larger than any number.

Is this definition correct in real calculus, not hyperreal calculus?

I heard that real number system doesn't have non-zero infinitesimal and wonder whether infinitesimal can be defined as 'situations'

So isn't above explanation flawed?

P S : sorry for bad english...

Answer (score 3):

In mainstream calculus / real analysis, "infinitesimals" do not exist. Therefore there is no definition for the word.

Without seeing a quote from your book, is it hard to know what it means by bringing up the concept. Unless it's presenting *non-standard analysis* (but if it does that, it should have told you very explicitly), a reasonable guess could be that the book is trying to present some of the *intuition* that motivated the pioneers of calculus -- but that intuition was later replaced by precise definitions involving limits and *no infinitesimals*.

Comment: "Therefore there is no definition for the word." I disagree with this: just because nothing satisfies the definition doesn't mean it doesn't make sense. E.g. "There are no infinitesimals" is a perfectly good theorem of standard analysis.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: You could say that. What I'm trying to express is that such a definition is not part of the common _development_ of real analysis, so it doesn't make particular sense to ask "what is the definition of infinitesimal _in real analysis_".

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Ah! That book says both 0 and infinitesimal are notated by 0 and limit that approches to 0 but not 0 like $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty} {\lim} \dfrac{1}{2^n}$ is called infinitesimal. Also it said result of infinitesimal × $\infty$ is undifined, but 0 × $\infty$ is 0! Is explanation of my book completely flawed?